# How to show only certain data in the woocommerce product page shortcode

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

i want to use the product page shortcode to add woocommerce product to my wordpress post. What I want to show is only the title, product image and the short description but not the whole product page. Is there any way I can achieve this? 
http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-11

Answer (score 0):

The product shortcode includes the `content-product.php` - this leaves you with a couple of options. You can either:

1. [Override this template with your on template by copying it to your theme folder](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/)
2. Or you can unhook some of the actions that load the the various parts of the page. For example, if you wanted to remove the ratings tab, you can use `remove_action()` like so:

`remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_rating', 10 );`

A full list of all the hooks can be found in `woocommerce/includes/wc-template-hooks.php`

Please note that either of these actions will affect *all* product ages, not just the ones rendered with the shortcode. If you want to change *just* the pages rendered via shortcodes then your best bet is to copy and edit the template as required (as per option 1 above) but save it in your theme folder with a different name (something like `content-product-short.php`). Then create your own shortcode function that fetches your new template - look at the function inside `class-wc-shortcodes.php` to get the idea.